# Can't solve 'NoneType' object is not iterable TypeError

Tags: python, nonetype

Links:
main.py: http://pastebin.com/19qBqWcF

Classes folder:

game.py: http://pastebin.com/P7Degwna
(I don't have enough reputation to post more than two links. The following broken links are for completeness but their code I believe is totally fine)

magic.py: http:// pastebin.com/wpwSCDe7

inventory.py: http:// pastebin.com/8kFXJne1

I'm trying to become a better programmer and have been following a tutorial on a simple battle system. Currently implementing enemy battle tactics.

I'm trying to program such that if an enemy chooses to heal and has over 50% remaining they reselect a spell.
Whenever this happens I get the following error from my code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kyle/PycharmProjects/battle/main.py", line 160, in <module>
    choose_attack, spell, magic_dmg = enemy.choose_enemy_spell()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Here is a dump of the output to terminal before that:

```
ACTIONS:
    1. Attack
    2. Magic
    3. Items
Choose action:1

TARGET:
    1. Ganon
    2. Vaati
Choose target:1
player attacked enemy for 284 points of damage.


Begin method
Curaga INSIDE CLASS
This is happening.
Begin method
Meteor INSIDE CLASS
1186 INSIDE CLASS INSIDE METHOD INSIDE FINAL ELSE
```

I can see my player takes their turn and then the enemy chooses the cure spell, has too much HP so chooses another spell and then I get the noneType error.

Whenever another spell thats isnt curaga is chosen first time around the code works just fine.

### Relevent code sections:

#### This is from my main program

```
#Create Black Magic
fire = Spell("Fire", 25, 600, "black") #create object fire from class Spell
thunder = Spell("Thunder", 25, 600, "black")
blizzard = Spell("Blizzard", 25, 600, "black")
meteor = Spell("Meteor", 40, 1200, "black")
quake = Spell("Quake", 32, 900, "black")

#Create White Magic
cure = Spell("Cure", 25, 620, "white")
cura = Spell("cura", 32, 1500, "white")
curaga = Spell("Curaga", 50, 6000, "white")


#Create lists of magic and items associated with players
player_magic = [fire, thunder, blizzard, meteor, cure, cura] #Create list of magic spell objects for object player
player_items = [{"item": potion, "quantity": 15}, {"item": hipotion, "quantity": 5}, {"item": superpotion, "quantity": 5},
            {"item": elixer, "quantity": 5}, {"item": hielixer, "quantity": 2}, {"item": grenade, "quantity": 5},] #Create list of item objects for object player
#Creat lists of magic and items associated with enemies
enemy_spells = [fire, meteor, curaga]
eneny_items = []

#Istantiate Player objects
player1 = Person("Zelda", 3260, 132, 300, 34, player_magic, player_items)
#Inistantiating object player using class Person
player2 = Person("Link ", 4160, 188, 311, 34, player_magic, player_items)
player3 = Person("Sheik", 3089, 174, 288, 34, player_magic, player_items)
#Instantiate Enemy objects
enemy1 = Person("Vaati", 1250, 130, 560, 325, enemy_spells, [])
enemy2 = Person("Ganon", 18200, 701, 535, 25, enemy_spells, [])
#Instantiating object enemy using class Person
enemy3 = Person("Vaati", 1250, 130, 560, 325, enemy_spells, [])

# Enemy chose to use magic
if enemy_choice == 1:
    choose_attack, spell, magic_dmg = enemy.choose_enemy_spell()
    enemy.reduce_mp(spell.cost)
    if spell.type == "white":  # Check type of spell of object spell to determine how to handle the chosen spell.
        enemy.heal(magic_dmg)  # White typer means heal
        print(bcolours.OKBLUE + "\n" + spell.name, " heals", enemy.name + str(magic_dmg),
              "HP." + bcolours.ENDC)
    elif spell.type == "black":  # black type means do damage
        target = random.randrange(0, 3)
        players[target].take_damage(magic_dmg)
        print(bcolours.OKBLUE + "\n" + enemy.name.replace(" ", "") + "'s " + spell.name, "deals",
              str(magic_dmg), "points of damage to " + players[target].name + bcolours.ENDC)
        if players[target].get_hp() == 0:
            print(players[target].name + " has died.")
            del players[target]
```

#### This is from a file containing classes

```
#Determine the spell the enemy chooses to use
def choose_enemy_spell(self):

    print("Begin method")
    choose_attack = 0
    magic_choice = random.randrange(0, len(self.magic))
    spell = self.magic[magic_choice]
    magic_dmg = spell.generate_damage()
    print(spell.name, "INSIDE CLASS")
    pct = (self.hp / self.maxhp)*100 #percentage of health remaining
    if self.mp < 25:
        print("This probably isnt happening")
        choose_attack = 1
        return choose_attack, spell, magic_dmg
    if  (spell.type == "white" and pct > 50) or self.mp < spell.cost:
        print("This is happening.")
        self.choose_enemy_spell()
    else:
        print(magic_dmg, "INSIDE CLASS INSIDE METHOD INSIDE FINAL ELSE")
        return choose_attack, spell, magic_dmg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `return` missing on line 172 in http://pastebin.com/P7Degwna.

Change:

```
self.choose_enemy_spell()
```

To:

```
return self.choose_enemy_spell()
```

Here is the debugging thought process:

- First look at the traceback message, `Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/Kyle/PycharmProjects/battle/main.py", line 160, in choose_attack, spell, magic_dmg = enemy.choose_enemy_spell() TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
- What it is telling you is that `enemy.choose_enemy_spell()` returned *None* instead of a 3-tuple.
- Next, look at the code in `Person.choose_enemy_spell` to examine all the exit paths to see which one is a problem.
- The returns on lines 169 and 175 both correctly return a 3-tuple, `return choose_attack, spell, magic_dmg`.  But, the code on line 172 computes the intended result without returning it.  That is why you only see the error when `(spell.type == "white" and pct > 50) or self.mp < spell.cost` evaluates to true.

Otherwise, your code looks nice.  Hope this little debugging exercise meets your skill-building goals :-)

Comment: Thanks very much for your response! Seems like such a simple error but its really cleared up the process in mind!

In my head I was with that line of code moving back to the start of the method and expecting it to do so until it reached the else statement

Now I'm thinking actually it beginning the method, moving into the elf statement beginning the method again and reaching the else statement and returning that to the elif statement which was then not returning anything to the main body of code which was expected!

Thanks!